How to prove that $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}sgn(t)\sqrt{|t|}dt$ is convex?
Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}sgn(t)\sqrt{|t|}dt$. Prove that $g(x)$ is a convex function.
I have proven that its second derivative is positive for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, but is this enought to say that $g$ is convex?
I also tried to show that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds that $[g'(x)-g'(y)](x-y)\geq0$. For this I have check cases where $x,y>0$, also $x,y<0$, but when it comes to the case $x<0$ and $y>0$, I failed.
How to proceed?

"is this enough to say that $g$ is convex?" --> Look at $g(x)=e^{-|x|}$

I assume you got $g''(x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{|x|}}$?

Surely it would be easier to note that $g(x) = {2 \over 3} |x|^{3 \over 2}$?

You should find that $g'(x) = sgn(x)\sqrt{|x|}$ for $x\in \mathbb R$ by FTC, as the integrand is continuous. Then we just need to show that $g'$ is increasing on $\mathbb R$:
Let $x,y\in \mathbb R$ with $x< y$.

Case $1$: If $x \geq 0$, then since the square root function is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, $g'(x) = \sqrt x < \sqrt y = g'(y)$.
Case $2$: If $y \leq 0$, then $|x| > |y| \geq 0$, thus $\sqrt{|y|} > \sqrt{|x|}$. Then multiplying by $-1$, $g'(x) < g'(y)$.
Case $3$: If $x < 0 < y$, then $g'(x) < g'(0) < g'(y)$ using both cases $1$ (apply to $(0,y)$) and $2$ (apply to $(x,0)$).

Thus $g'$ is increasing, implying $g$ is convex.
